# Filter out empty 'multiple lines of text' column(s) in list view. SP 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, list-view, splistitem

I need to filter out items that have empty 'multiple lines of text' columns in my list view. Traditional filter methods do not work. See images below. Please help!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please check this link it worked with me https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13273/how-can-i-filter-a-view-using-a-blank-multi-line-field/13279#13279

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's by design that the 'multiple lines of text' columns only can be filtered using 'Contains' and 'begins with'.

As a workaround, I recommend you use SharePoint Designer to edit the list view, then use Filter in the List View Tools options to filter items when multiple lines of text column is null.

[image]

Reference: [SharePoint Designer 2013 – How to modify List View web part filters and parameters](http://blog.pentalogic.net/2014/05/sharepoint-designer-2013-how-to-modify-list-view-filters-parameters/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you couldn't apply equals/not equals filtering for the "multiple line of text" column in the view.

You can try the above SharePoint Designer solution (or) alternatively you can make that column a mandatory one to prevent empty comments.